# Could not find the expo package in your project - react-native link

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created an expo project using **expo-cli** and ejected it to regular native-script project, but while running **react-native link** I am getting this message:

> Could not find the "expo" package in your project when configuring the
>   packager while running react-native link

can someone please help me resolving the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have your project ejected successfully ? are there separate android and ios folders now ? On what were you using react-native link ?

Comment: @shubham yes, I ejected it successfully I can see both ios and android folders. The error message is coming every time when I run npm run android or react-native link

Comment: In my experience, react-native link is a bit buggy. what were your dependencies ?

Comment: Am also experiencing this error, after ejecting successfully from expo.

Comment: Did You find the solution?

Comment: I have crna project and using it, project with expo-cli still having issues.